# Append text in textbox on another form?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, textbox

I have 2 forms.  On `Form2`, I have a textbox and a button.  When I press the button, I want it to append the text in the textbox to a textbox on `Form1`.  Here's my code:

On `Form2`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frm1.AppendTxt(textBox1.Text);
    this.Close();
}
```

On `Form1`:

```
public void AppendTxt(string text)
{
    this.body.AppendText(text);
    MessageBox.Show(body.Text);
}
```

For some reason, the text isn't showing up in the textbox on `Form1`.  However, the message box that pops up shows the text I input on `Form2`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `body.Text += " " + text;`

Comment: var frm = Application.OpenForms["Form1"] ?? new Form1();                    frm.body.Text += " " + text;

Comment: @rcarter: `frm` will have the wrong static type, lookup of the member `body` will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're changing the textbox inside a hidden copy of `Form1`, not the instance that's displayed on the screen.

Try passing the `Form1` handle to `Form2`'s constructor, and saving it in a class member variable (also called *field*) to use inside the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create getters and setters for your textbox so it will be exposed as part of your form class and you can access it as a form object 
first forn

```
   public string sometext
    {
        get { return sometext.Text; }
        set { sometext.Text = value; }
    }
```

second form

```
Form1 form= new Form1();
 form.sometext = "some name";
```

here is another short solution i found 
In Form1  initiate form 2

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.Owner = (Form)this;
form2.Show();
```

and in Form2's

```
this.Owner.Controls.Find("TextBox1",true).First().Text="Hi!!!!"
```

Comment: Apart from the naming collision between the textbox and property, this doesn't help get access to the instance of `Form1` that already exists, it creates a new (hidden) instance.

Answer (score 0):

Passing values from form to form.

You can try this. first you can declare a variable that all your forms can access
like this one,

```
string yourValue;
```

PS: declare that your class

From form1, you can pass a value to that class.
like this,

```
YourClass.yourValue = textbox1.text;
```

Once have a value. pass it to your second form like.

```
textbox2.text = YourClass.yourValue;
```

Hope it helps you. :D

Comment: That looks like jQuery?  This question is tagged `c#`, not `javascript`.  Pretty sure it's WinForms, not ASP, based on the event handler signature and use of `MessageBox`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two form: form1 and form2. Two form is opening. In form2 you have one textbox(txt2) and one button(btn2). In form1 you have one textbox(txt1).  When user type something on txt2 and click btn2, the text in txt2 will be append to txt1. This is what you want?

If yes:
In form2, you should create a delegate:

```
// Declare a delegate
public delegate void GetValue(string value);
// Declare event with delegate
public event GetValue btn2_Clicked;
```

Then, in form2, you create a function to handle that event: Name of function is the same with name of event you just declare and add prefix "On" in it. Like this:

```
public void Onbtn2_Clicked(string value)
{
    if (btn2_Clicked != null)
    {
        btn2_Clicked(value);
    }
}
```

After that, in btn2 click event, rise your event just created:

```
private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Onbtn2_Clicked(txt2.Text);
}
```

Ok, that is done in form2. Comeback form1 to finish:
I assume form2 is opened when user click a button(btn1) in form1, so in btn1 click event:

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create form2
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
    // Handle btn2 click
    frm2.btn2_Clicked += new Form2.GetValue(frm2_btn2_Clicked);
    // Show form2
    frm2.Show();

}

void frm2_btn2_Clicked(string value)
{
    // When btn2 is clicked, the text in txt2 will be assign to txt1
    txt1.Text = value;                
}
```

And the text will be assign to txt1 in form1

Answer (score 0):

How about just change the txtBox in the Form2.designer.cs from private to public?

```
private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
```

to

```
public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
```

This way you can just send it like this in Form2:

```
Form1 frm1 = new Form1();

private void button1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
frm1.textBox1.AppendText(textBox2);
```

textBox2 being the one where you enter your text in Form2